# Adding additional authenticated data to AES-GCM on Android

Tags: android, encryption, spongycastle, aes-gcm

I'm trying to add the additional authenticated data (AAD) to AES-GCM on Android. I see the Java 7 version of [Cipher notes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) about using `GCMParameterSpec` and the `updateAAD(...)` method but given Android is Java 6 based I'm all out of ideas. I'm using Spongycastle as the crypto library

```
  GCMParameterSpec s = new GCMParameterSpec(...);
  cipher.init(..., s);
  cipher.updateAAD(...);  // AAD
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks @andrey - I found a more complete sample also form the [BC mailing list](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/InvalidCipherTextException-with-GCMBlockCipher-td1467111.html)

```
public void testGCM() {
    try {
        byte iv[] = "123456789012".getBytes();
        byte inMsg[] = "11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
                .getBytes();
        byte aad[] = "123456789012123456789012123456789012345678901234567890123456"
                .getBytes();
        byte key[] = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb".getBytes();

        System.out.println("inMsgLen===" + inMsg.length);

        // encrypt
        AEADParameters parameters = new AEADParameters(
                new KeyParameter(key), 128, iv, aad);
        GCMBlockCipher gcmEngine = new GCMBlockCipher(new AESFastEngine());
        gcmEngine.init(true, parameters);

        byte[] encMsg = new byte[gcmEngine.getOutputSize(inMsg.length)];
        int encLen = gcmEngine.processBytes(inMsg, 0, inMsg.length, encMsg,
                0);
        encLen += gcmEngine.doFinal(encMsg, encLen);

        System.out.println("encLen===" + encLen);

        // decrypt
        gcmEngine.init(false, parameters);

        byte[] decMsg = new byte[gcmEngine.getOutputSize(encMsg.length)];
        int decLen = gcmEngine.processBytes(encMsg, 0, encMsg.length,
                decMsg, 0);
        decLen += gcmEngine.doFinal(decMsg, decLen);

        System.out.println("decLen===" + decLen);

        System.out.println("MSG===" + new String(decMsg));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From BC [mailing list](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/AES-GCM-with-AAD-td1467570.html):

> It seems an oversight on our part means the JCE provider does not 
>   currently expose a mechanism for setting the AAD (also applies to other 
>   AEAD ciphers: CCM, EAX).
>
> In the lightweight API, the AAD is passed to the cipher (`.init`) via an 
>   instance of `AEADParameters` (the field 'associatedText').

With lightweight API you can also provide AAD data via `processAADBytes()` method exposed by [AEADBlockCipher](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/index.html?org/bouncycastle/crypto/modes/AEADBlockCipher.html) interface.